# Where did Paul Gerber go wrong in arriving at the same equation as Einstein in explaining the Mercury anomaly?

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, history, solar-system, precession

We know that Einstein admitted that Paul Gerber's 1898 formula explaining the anomaly of Mercury's perihelion was the same as his own. Reportedly Gerber had made a mistake somewhere, so - even though his equation was correct - he could not have arrived at this equation on the basis of his own premises. Can anyone explain - preferably in layman's terms - at what point Gerber went astray in his calculation?

Comment: Who was Paul Gerber? Can you give a reference?

Comment: I admit to not knowing anything about Gerber or his calculation, but note that it is *calculating the anomaly from first principles* that had made Einstein's discovery stellar, not merely quantifying the precession. I hardly believe that anybody could employ the techniques of General Relativity in 1898.

Comment: I can point to a brief reference to Gerber's work in the first few paragraphs here: http://mathpages.com/rr/s8-10/8-10.htm

Comment: The  original work  (English translation): http://www.alternativephysics.org/gerber/Perihelion.htm

Comment: Thank you all for your responses and links. Wiki page on Gerber at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gerber#Controversy . Gerber allegedly gave too high a value for the light deflection. I find this interesting because the "good" photos [eight I believe] from Sobral were interpreted at 1.98, about 14 percent higher than the Einsteinian prediction of 1.71. The "poor" photos from the other telescope at Sobral agreed with the Newtonian estimate of .87. Principe's two poor photos gave 1.61. I'm curious to know if anyone could figure what the higher Gerberian deflection value might be.